# jQuery: Stop Animation on mouse over

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function like this:

```
$(function()
var ticker = function()
{
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('#ticker li:first').animate( {marginTop: '-22px'}, 250, function()
    {
       $(this).detach().appendTo('ul#ticker').removeAttr('style');});
       ticker();
    }, 1500);       
};

$('#ticker').hover(function() { 
    $('#ticker').stop();         
});

ticker();

});
```

I tried to stop animation on mouse over using `.stop()` API, and play animation when the mouse is moved out but I have no idea about that. Please help.

**UPDATE** :
Solved: http://jsbin.com/ilated

Comment: To be clear: you're able to stop the animation, but need to be able to  resume it on mouseout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also need a `clearTimeout( )` call in your `.hover( )` function to clear out the already running timeout.  Then in the 'mouseout' portion of the `.hover(` function (the second argument), put another call to `ticker( )` to re-enable it.

The following is untested:

```
var ticker_timeout = false;
$(function()
var ticker = function()
{
    ticker_timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    $('#ticker li:first').animate( {marginTop: '-22px'}, 250, function()
    {
       $(this).detach().appendTo('ul#ticker').removeAttr('style');});
       ticker();
    }, 1500);       
};

$('#ticker').hover(function() { 
    $('#ticker li:first').stop();
    clearTimeout(ticker_timeout);       
}, function( ) {
    ticker();
});

ticker();

});
```

**EDIT**: adeneo is correct, you need to stop the element that was animated.  fixed above

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the element that was animated:

```
$('#ticker li:first').stop();
```

Also, hover accepts two functions, not one, and you need to stop the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`hover` can take 2 callback, one for mouseenter and another for mouserleave. You can try something like this. Also after stopping the animation you should also clear the timeout if there is any.

```
$(function()
 var timerId;
 var ticker = function()
 {
    timerId = setTimeout(function(){
    $('#ticker li:first').animate( {marginTop: '-22px'}, 250, function()
    {
       $(this).detach().appendTo('ul#ticker').removeAttr('style');});
       ticker();
    }, 1500);       
 };

 $('#ticker').hover(function() { 
     $('#ticker  li:first').stop();         
     clearTimeout(timerId);   
 }, ticker);

 ticker();

});
```